# MVC Database first with stored procedure error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am trying to create an MVC application that will use a database first approach.  (existing database)  I followed the tutorials I found online and have the CRUD procedures mapped.  On create I get the error  *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.String'.*

Here is the procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AddAdminUser]

@AdminID nvarchar(15),
@PersonName nvarchar(50),
@Email nvarchar(50),
@RoleID tinyint,
@ReceiveNotifications bit

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Message varchar(100)

IF EXISTS(SELECT PersonName FROM dbo.AdminUsers WHERE AdminID = @AdminID)
    BEGIN

        SET @Message = 'A user with this ID already exists'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT
            dbo.AdminUsers
        VALUES
        (
            @AdminID,
            @PersonName,
            @Email,
            @RoleID,
            @ReceiveNotifications,
            0,
            0
        )

        DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID()
        DECLARE @Len int
        DECLARE @Min tinyint 
        DECLARE @Range tinyint  
        DECLARE @Exclude varchar(50)
        DECLARE @Char char
        DECLARE @Password nvarchar(20)

        SET @Len = 12
        SET @Min = 35
        SET @Range = 74
        SET @Exclude  = '0:;`0l1-<>/\[]()'''
        SET @Password = ''

        -- Create a temporary password
        WHILE @Len > 0
            BEGIN
                SELECT @Char = char(ROUND(RAND() * @Range + @Min,0))
                IF CHARINDEX(@Char,@Exclude) = 0 
                    BEGIN
                        SET @Password = @Password + @Char
                        SET @Len = @Len -1
                    END
            END
        INSERT
            dbo.AdminLogins
        VALUES
        (
            @AdminID,
            HASHBYTES('SHA2_512',@Password+CAST(@salt as nvarchar(36))),
            @salt
        )

        --SET @Message = 'here is your temporary password ' + @Password
    END 
--SELECT @Message AS Message



Exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='email',
@recipients= @Email,
@subject='Your account has been created',
@body=@Message
```

Here is the Model

```
    namespace AMS_MVC.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AdminUser
    {
        public AdminUser()
        {
            this.Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
            this.Districts = new HashSet<District>();
            this.Divisions = new HashSet<Division>();
            this.Regions = new HashSet<Region>();
            this.Zones = new HashSet<Zone>();
            this.Locations = new HashSet<Location>();
        }

        public string AdminID { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public byte RoleID { get; set; }
        public bool ReceiveNotifications { get; set; }
        public bool ChangePW { get; set; }
        public bool Deactivated { get; set; }

        public virtual AdminLogin AdminLogin { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Division> Divisions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AMS_MVC.Models;

namespace AMS_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class AdminUsersController : Controller
    {
        private MVC_AMSEntities1 db = new MVC_AMSEntities1();


        // GET: AdminUsers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var adminUsers = db.AdminUsers.Include(a => a.AdminLogin).Include(a => a.Role);
            return View(adminUsers.ToList());
        }

        // GET: AdminUsers/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            AdminUser adminUser = db.AdminUsers.Find(id);
            if (adminUser == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(adminUser);
        }



        // GET: AdminUsers/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.AdminID = new SelectList(db.AdminLogins, "AdminID", "AdminID");

            ViewBag.RoleID = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleID", "RoleName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: AdminUsers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AdminID,PersonName,Email,RoleID,ReceiveNotifications")] AdminUser adminUser)
        //public ActionResult Create()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.AdminUsers.Add(adminUser);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.AdminID = new SelectList(db.AdminLogins, "AdminID", "AdminID", adminUser.AdminID);
            ViewBag.RoleID = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleID", "RoleName", adminUser.RoleID);
            return View(adminUser);
        }

        // GET: AdminUsers/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            AdminUser adminUser = db.AdminUsers.Find(id);
            if (adminUser == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.AdminID = new SelectList(db.AdminLogins, "AdminID", "AdminID", adminUser.AdminID);
            ViewBag.RoleID = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleID", "RoleName", adminUser.RoleID);
            return View(adminUser);
        }

        // POST: AdminUsers/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "AdminID,PersonName,Email,RoleID,ReceiveNotifications,ChangePW,Deactivated")] AdminUser adminUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(adminUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.AdminID = new SelectList(db.AdminLogins, "AdminID", "AdminID", adminUser.AdminID);
            ViewBag.RoleID = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleID", "RoleName", adminUser.RoleID);
            return View(adminUser);
        }

        // GET: AdminUsers/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            AdminUser adminUser = db.AdminUsers.Find(id);
            if (adminUser == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(adminUser);
        }

        // POST: AdminUsers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            AdminUser adminUser = db.AdminUsers.Find(id);
            db.AdminUsers.Remove(adminUser);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Create View

```
@model AMS_MVC.Models.AdminUser

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Admin User";
}

<h2>Admin User Control Panel</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create Admin User</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdminID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdminID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdminID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersonName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleID, "RoleID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("RoleID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReceiveNotifications, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReceiveNotifications)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReceiveNotifications, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And here is the procedure mapping
[Image of mapped procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCAO9.png)

I know the procedure works because I can run it in SSMS.  This is driving me up a wall.  I have been working on this one issue for close to a month now.   None of the google searches i have done have been any help.   I really need some idea what to do to get this corrected.

Comment: When debugging can you check ReceiveNotifications value in post Create  method whether it is string or bool

Comment: You have provided too much code. Just post the code that's related to the issue. By the way, obviously, there's a problem with `ReceiveNotifications`. You just need to make sure it has the right datatype.

Comment: One more thing; why do you need a stored procedure to add a new record?

Comment: this looks like straight up scaffolding generated code.. have you stepped thru any of it?

Comment: What is the editor  you see for `model.ReceiveNotifications` in your MVC page? Is it a checkbox or something else?

Comment: My recommendation is to step  through the  `Create` method where you call `SaveChanges` method. In this method, check the value of `adminUser.ReceiveNotifications`. What is the value you see?

Comment: I am pretty sure that a string value is getting passed for `adminUser.ReceiveNotifications`. In that case  you would need to alter the editor for this property so its not bound to a model property. Just use another parameter to your `Create` action method  called `stringBoolValue`. Finally set the `adminUser.ReceiveNotifications` property before `SaveChanges` is called.

Comment: I have provided a detailed answer. Please check it out.

Comment: @ataravati,   Because it inserts into MULTIPLE tables.    Habit from years of not setting permissions for select insert update delete and always using sprocs to prevent SQL injection

Comment: @atravarti   if I new which code to look at I would not have provided it   but better too much code than not enough would you not agree?

Comment: @MirandaJohnson, you didn't have to post the whole controller, for example. Clearly, the issue doesn't have to do with the Delete action.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the detailed approach mentioned below, please read the other approach mentioned at end of the answer, which might solve your issue with minimal code changes in a quick time frame.

Change the editor for `adminUser.ReceiveNotifications` in your markup to what's given below i.e. remove the markup that emits the editor for this property.

```
<input id="recNotifications" name="recNotifications" value="false"  type="checkbox" />
```

Then change the Create action method to what is given below. You will notice that an extra parameter to receive a boolean value from checkbox is added to the method and also a line of code that sets the `adminUser.ReceiveNotifications` property.

```
  // POST: AdminUsers/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "AdminID,PersonName,Email,
      RoleID")] AdminUser adminUser, bool recNotifications = false)
    //public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //add the line below and also the extra parameter below
        adminUser.ReceiveNotifications =  reNotifications;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.AdminUsers.Add(adminUser);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.AdminID = new SelectList(db.AdminLogins, "AdminID", "AdminID", adminUser.AdminID);
        ViewBag.RoleID = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleID", "RoleName", adminUser.RoleID);
        return View(adminUser);
    }
```

**Also, another approach you could try before the above solution** is to define a default value for `adminUser.ReceiveNotifications` property in your model constructor using code like below. If you follow this approach, then do not make any changes to markup or the action method for `Create`.

```
 public AdminUser()
        {
            this.Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
            this.Districts = new HashSet<District>();
            this.Divisions = new HashSet<Division>();
            this.Regions = new HashSet<Region>();
            this.Zones = new HashSet<Zone>();
            this.Locations = new HashSet<Location>();
           //add default value for ReceiveNotifications
            this.ReceiveNotifications = false;
        }
```

Comment: Was it the missing default value for this property?

Comment: no,  i had inadvertently added something meant for another item   so instead of   [Required, Display(Name = "Receive New Applicant Notifications")]
        public bool ReceiveNotifications { get; set; }    it said  [Required, Display(Name = "Receive New Applicant Notifications"),StringLength(15)]
        public bool ReceiveNotifications { get; set; }

Comment: Ok. Good. You defined the type as string.